# Performing unknown number of Ajax requests in jQuery one after another

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to JS, so please forgive me if I have any mistakes.

I have a "unknown" number of URLs in a array, and I have to get them using Ajax, but not  asynchronously. I want them to be retrieved one after another, but my current code fires everything at the same time.

Any assistance is appreciated - my current code is something like below:

```
urls = ["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.bing.com"] // the number of urls in this array changes

var gets = []

$.each(urls, function(index, url) {
  gets.push($.ajax({
    url: url
  }));
});
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235237/jquery-how-to-use-multiple-ajax-calls-one-after-the-end-of-the-other)

Answer (score 1):

Because ajax returns a promise, you can chain obtaining the result with the next invocation.

```
var urls = ["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.bing.com"]

(function(arrayurls, index) {
  if(index >= arrayurls.length) return;
  var url = arrayurls[index];
  var thisfunction = arguments.callee;
  $.ajax({ url: url }).done(function(result) {
     //Do something with the result.
     thisfunction(arrayurls, index + 1) // Reinvoke the function over different arguments.
  });
})(urls, 0);
```

Named variant to get rid of `arguments.callee`:

```
var handle = function(arrayurls: string[], index: number) {
  if(index >= arrayurls.length) return;
  var url = arrayurls[index];
  $.ajax({ url: url }).done(function(result) {
     //Do something with the result.
     handle(arrayurls, index + 1) // Reinvoke the request over the next URL arguments.
  });
};
handle(urls, 0);
```

If the number of urls is going to change over time while this invocation is made, you can always copy the url array with `urls.slice(0)`;

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `async=false` parameter with your ajax call. This makes the next ajax calls to wait until the previous call has completed. Something like below code should work:

```
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "get",
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
                your logic
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but async: false locks the entire browser, so it's not the case. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785886/2561834. You need an class/function to handle your stack of requests.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `async: false`. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).