# ajax calls iterating through javascript array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying iterate through a series of inputs from a form.  foreach input i want to fire an ajax call that will only fire after previous call was completed.
I read a [Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235237/jquery-how-to-use-multiple-ajax-calls-one-after-the-end-of-the-other) here.

```
$(function(){

 var data = [];

    $('input[type=text]').each(function(e,i){
            var val = $(this).val();
            data.push(val);
    });

    current = 0;
    function do_ajax() {
            if (current < data.length) {
                    $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            data:"id="+data[current].value,
                            url:"tester.php",
                            success:function(result){
                                    $('#div').append(result);
                                    current++;
                                    do_ajax();
                            }
                    });
            };
    }
    do_ajax();
 });
```

HTML

```
    <input type='text' id='users[][name]' value='Bob'>
    <input type='text' id='users[][name]' value='Frank'>
    <input type='text' id='users[][name]' value='Tom'>
    <input type='text' id='users[][name]' value='Joe'>
    <input type='text' id='users[][name]' value='Bill'>
    <input type='text' id='users[][name]' value='Gary'>

<div id='done'></div>
<div id='div'>DIV</div>
```

tester.php for testing is simply:

```
 echo $_POST['id'];
```

i cant get anything returned from tester.php except:

```
undefined
```

what do i need to put for id in the data section of ajax call?

I have tried:

```
data[current].value;

data[current].val;

data[current].val();
```

EDIT::::::

Using accepted solution i also had to change:

```
  $('#div').append(result);
```

to:

```
 $('#div').append(result.responseText);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just send all the data at once

Comment: this is a stripped down version of what I am trying to do.  i posted only enough to get my question across.  each ajax call builds off the results of the previous.

Comment: Okay then -> https://jsfiddle.net/89ggmrgn/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `value` property, change this:

```
data:"id="+data[current].value
```

to this:

```
data:"id="+data[current]
```

and also use `complete` instead of `success` callback because `complete` executes after `success` and `error` callback

Comment: Is the array built "correctly"(is it bad code to not have index)?  should i build it with index:value?  should i use an object instead?

Comment: actually have to retract my acceptance.  the result of echo $_POST['id'] is 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: can you see in the developer tool in network tab what form data is being submitted.

Comment: yea, well no, i can see the response from tester.php is "Bill" or "Joe" or whatever.  so it appears $('#div').append(result) isnt appending, or appending ""

Comment: the numbers were a mistake in my comment above. the result of tester.php seems to be correct, but nothing is being appended to #div.   now.  in the complete of ajax, if i do $('#div').append(result+",<br>");   i see [object Object], and so on.

Comment: try to use `complete`, instead of `success`.

Comment: I have done that, and i also replaced append with alert(result);  and get [object Object] in the alert window.

Comment: got it.  alert(result.responseText) shows the response from tester.php.