# javascript Code is working fine in debug mode with out any error, but its showing Argument out of Range error in normal Mode?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am stuck in a situation where I am hitting multiple ajax calls on controller while working in debugger mode everything works fine but in normal mode it showing argument out of range exception

```
 for (var i = 0; i < artdata.length; i++) {
         addNewStepMultiple(artdata[i], i)
            }

 function addNewStepMultiple(artifactData, index) {
            if (artifactData != null) {
                var tcIndex, data, url;
                var suiteId = serviceFactory.getComponentInfo().id;
                var gridInstance = $("#Suite_Grid").data("kendoGrid");
                if (gridInstance._data.length == 0) {
                    tcIndex = -1 + index + 1;
                } else {
                    tcIndex = $("#Suite_Grid").data("kendoGrid").select().index();
                    if (tcIndex == -1) {
                        tcIndex = tcIndex + index;
                    } else {
                        tcIndex = tcIndex + index + 1;
                    }
                }
                console.log('tcIndex' + tcIndex);
                var newTcIndex = tcIndex;
                var treeBinding = JSON.stringify(artifactData);
                url = "/Suite/AddNewStep";
                data = { SuiteID: suiteId, position: tcIndex, artifactModel: treeBinding };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (res) {
                        debugger; //$scope.SuiteData.data(res);
                        bindSuiteGrid(res); //$scope.SuiteData.data(result)
                        $scope.setChanges();
                        //var tr = grid.element.find('tbody tr:eq(' + (newindex) + ')'); //.addClass('k-state-selected')
                        //  grid.select(tr);
                        var tr = $('#Suite_Grid table tr:eq(' + (res.length) + ')')
                        $("#Suite_Grid").data("kendoGrid").select(tr);
                        loadingStop("#vertical-splitter", ".btnTestLoader");
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        debugger
                        loadingStop("#vertical-splitter", ".btnTestLoader");
                        serviceFactory.showError($scope, error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Please let me know how to solve the problem.

Comment: where exactly is your issue? check for line number in browser console

Comment: When we are processing multiple ajax call request to controller then its showing error. I think that code is getting skip

Comment: what is the prototype of bindSuiteGrid()  function?

Comment: Well, you can provide `AddNewStep` action method which may be origin of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Check if something has been skipped or unassigned in browser console, pay attention especially to lines after `debugger`.

Comment: In bindSuiteGrid() A template of grid columns and data bound is set

Comment: code is working fine in debugger and not showing error. While in normal mode is showing error so how can i debug the problem.

Comment: Do these steps: check browser console during testing in normal mode for any error returned, set breakpoint to where the problem comes and grab inner exception/stack trace information about the error.

Comment: On the JavaScript side, try using Console.Log(...). After it has failed, open the debugger, and view the output.

Comment: Problem is coming from core of the code, some where in core the code execution sequence is getting skip, So how can i handle this.

Answer (score 0):

in your scenario loop can not wait up to your ajax request in normal mode. so  [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235237/jquery-how-to-use-multiple-ajax-calls-one-after-the-end-of-the-other) to know the how to make a multiple ajax calls