# Multiple ajax request parallel issue

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to make 100 ajax request in $.when at a time on Chrome :

```
var task = [];
List.forEach(function (item, index) {   // List length is 100       
    tasks.push(ajaxUploadTrackable(item));   
}

$.when.apply(null, tasks).then(function (result) {
  // do somthing
}
```

[image]

but some request got failed.
please give me any idea. 
is there pending time limitation or maximum number of requests at a time???

Comment: What reasons are indicated for the failed requests? Why do they fail? Do you have any indications on that in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery how to use multiple ajax calls one after the end of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235237/jquery-how-to-use-multiple-ajax-calls-one-after-the-end-of-the-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of loop check for sync and async

Put your AJAX call in a function and call it from the AJAX callback:
[check Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235323/6299088)