# How to launch 1 by 1 ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having some trouble. I'm trying to execute my ajax function 1 by 1, not all at the same time. I'm using `promise` but I have no more idea on how to achieve it. Here is my code :

```
function run_action(action){
    if(action == "login"){
        return $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {password: password},
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log('beforeSend login');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Success Login');
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log('Error Login');
            },
        })
    }
    if(action == "register"){
        return $.ajax({
            url: "register.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {password: password},
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log('beforeSend register');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Success Register');
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log('Error Register');
            },
        })
    }
}

var actions = ['register', 'login'];
services.forEach(checkActions);
function checkActions(item, index) {
    if (document.getElementById(item).checked) {
        var promise = run_action(item);
        promise.success(function (data) {
            console.log('Run after');
        });
        console.log('Run first')
    }
}
```

In this case `login` and `register` are both launched at the same time, `login` doesn't wait for `register` to finish so he can start processing.

Comment: on `success` call the next method.

Comment: you mean `promise.success(function (data) {
        run_action(item);
    });` ?

Comment: right! @executable you can look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31453579/2845389

Comment: It won't work in my case because I have many more functions and sometimes I disabled them from launching

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery how to use multiple ajax calls one after the end of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235237/jquery-how-to-use-multiple-ajax-calls-one-after-the-end-of-the-other)

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can't properly wait for `checkActions` from the outside, you could maintain a task queue for that:

```
 let queue = Promise.resolve();

 function checkActions(item, index) {
    queue = queue
     .then(() => run_action(item))
     .then(() => {
       console.log("Next item was processed", item);
       // Your code here
     });
   // Synchronous code here - This won't execute in order!
 }
```

Comment: I tried the solution but I'm having the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: What is the meaning of `queue = queue` ?

Comment: Whoops, that should have been mutable, fixed. ... It's `queue = queue.then(...).then(...);` ... or in other words it appends a new task to the chain

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code runs through the forEach loop with each action and invokes checkActions with that action, thus firing the request. Array.prototype.forEach executes synchronously (without any kind of check to the promises returned by $.ajax). The following would wait for 'register' to finish before firing 'login':

```
function checkActions(item) {
  if (document.getElementById(item).checked) {
    return run_action(item);
  }
}

checkActions('register')
  .then(data => {
    return checkActions('login');
  });
```

I'm not super familiar with jQuery's promise structure, so I used .then, but I believe you can use .success without issue as well.

Unrelated comment, your run_actions function should really be split into two functions (login and register) since they are completely unrelated aside from the fact that they are making requests.

Comment: But how to use it if I have like 10 more function ?

Answer (score 0):

First-  its not a good practice to trust a order-based function (AKA -  run them by the array order), run your functions according to logic.

For example: if the first function was failed - you dont want to run the next functions in the array.

If you consist to run the functions in array - you can use an async

```
async function runActions( actionsList ) {
  for(const action of actionsList) {
    await run_action( action );
  }
};
```

In general - we use the [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method to run anther function when specific promise is done. Like so:

```
promise.then( onSuccess => {
   // try to log in
}, onFail => {
   // tell the user the signup was failed
});
```

---

BTW - you can use the native [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instade of jQuery ajax, and get simple to use, promise-based way to communicate with your sever.

Like so:

```
fetch("login.php" , {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: {password: password}, // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then( ... )
```

Comment: I don't have only login, register function, I have plenty, it won't work in my case

Comment: @executable It doesn't matter what you do within your success function, you can call a function inside an Array at location of I, the logic is the same.

Comment: @executable and BTW  - Its not a good practice to trust a order-based function, run your functions according to logic. Don't look for shortcuts

Comment: Hmm ok, do you mind to post an example with more function in the main idea like register or login

Comment: And how do you use it in my `foreach` loop ?

Comment: @executable again, its not a good practice, but i edited my answer anyway. you can look for more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence